# Uniquely identify grouped data by non-sequential date ranges

Tags: sql-server

Help please, I have the following data in one of my MSSQL Data tables.

ID |StartDateTime  |EndDateTime    |OrderNo|
1  |12-08-01 08:00 |12-08-01 08:00 |6001   |
5  |12-08-01 09:00 |12-08-01 10:00 |6001   |
7  |12-08-01 10:00 |12-08-01 11:00 |6001   |
10 |12-08-01 11:00 |12-08-01 12:00 |6002   |
15 |12-08-01 12:00 |12-08-01 13:00 |6002   |
22 |12-08-01 13:00 |12-08-01 14:00 |6003   |
29 |12-08-01 14:00 |12-08-01 15:00 |6001   |
33 |12-08-01 15:00 |12-08-01 16:00 |6001   |
36 |12-08-01 16:00 |12-08-01 17:00 |6004   |

The problem is currently I have no way to tell if the OrderNo has been used multiple times. I cant tell that Order 6001 has been run twice.

I'd like to be able to add a new field to uniquely identify each run of an order from now on. But also go back over previous records and update them as well.

ID |StartDateTime  |EndDateTime    |OrderNo|Run|
1  |12-08-01 08:00 |12-08-01 08:00 |6001   |1  |
5  |12-08-01 09:00 |12-08-01 10:00 |6001   |1  |
7  |12-08-01 10:00 |12-08-01 11:00 |6001   |1  |
10 |12-08-01 11:00 |12-08-01 12:00 |6002   |1  |
15 |12-08-01 12:00 |12-08-01 13:00 |6002   |1  |
22 |12-08-01 13:00 |12-08-01 14:00 |6003   |1  |
29 |12-08-01 14:00 |12-08-01 15:00 |6001   |2  |
33 |12-08-01 15:00 |12-08-01 16:00 |6001   |2  |
36 |12-08-01 16:00 |12-08-01 17:00 |6004   |1  |

The idea being I can group by OrderNo and Run and will recieve the following.

OrderNo |Run |RunStart       |RunEnd         |
6001    | 1  |12-08-01 08:00 |12-08-01 11:00 |
6001    | 2  |12-08-01 14:00 |12-08-01 16:00 |
6002    | 1  |12-08-01 11:00 |12-08-01 13:00 |
6003    | 1  |12-08-01 13:00 |12-08-01 14:00 |
6004    | 1  |12-08-01 16:00 |12-08-01 17:00 |

I have tried multiple ways using ROW_NUMBER, CTE, cursors etc to run through the data. I have a feeling there is a simple solution but I can't figure it out.

I Hope this makes sense.

**EDIT**

I have changed the data tables to reference an extra complication, which I didn't include first time round. Aaron's solution provided would have worked fine. But it assumes the runs can only last for upto 2 hours (or rows). In my database these runs for n hours (or rows).  Im sorry I wasn't clear first time around, and I appreciate the help given thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit actually makes the problem simpler to me (possibly just because I missed a simpler island approach initially).

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT OrderNo, StartDateTime, EndDateTime,
    rn1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDateTime), 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY StartDateTIme)
  FROM dbo.table_name -- you need to change this
),
y AS
(
  SELECT OrderNo, Island = rn1 - rn, 
    rs = MIN(StartDateTime), 
    re = MAX(EndDateTime) 
  FROM x GROUP BY OrderNo, rn1 - rn
)
SELECT 
  OrderNo, 
  Run = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY rs),
  RunStart = rs, 
  RunEnd = rs
FROM y
ORDER BY OrderNo, Run;
```

---

Leaving my original answer for posterity.

---

There is probably a simpler way, but this gets the answer you're after using window functions.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT ID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, OrderNo,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY StartDateTime) 
  FROM dbo.table_name -- you need to change this
), y AS
(
  SELECT x.ID, x.StartDateTime, x.EndDateTime, x.OrderNo, x.rn,
      x2ID = x2.ID, x2S = x2.StartDateTime, x2E = x2.EndDateTime, 
      x2O = x2.OrderNo, x2rn = x2.rn
  FROM x LEFT OUTER JOIN x AS x2
  ON x.OrderNo = x2.OrderNo
  AND x.rn = x2.rn - 1
  AND x.ID = x2.ID - 1
)
SELECT 
  OrderNo, 
  Run = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY StartDateTime),
  RunStart = StartDateTime, 
  RunEnd = COALESCE(x2E, EndDateTime) 
FROM y
WHERE x2ID IS NOT NULL 
OR NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM y AS y2 WHERE y2.OrderNo = y.OrderNo AND y2.x2rn = y.rn
)
ORDER BY OrderNo, Run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Aaron.  But this doesn't quite work as required.  Your code is not grouping the runs correctly. In the example rows 1 & 2 should be grouped as run 1 for order 6001 and row 6 should be run 2 for order 6001.  Your code treats each row as as a run.

Comment: @user1612171 seems to work exactly as expected for the sample data you provided. Perhaps you have edge cases your sample data didn't mention? Please see a repro with sample data here, and let me know where it doesn't meet your requirements: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f516/1

Comment: I think I see the problem.  In my example data the id is sequential with dates.  This is not the case in the database, it's the PK thats why i included it.

Comment: So provide sample data that is actually representative.

Comment: ID|StartDateTime |EndDateTime |OrderNo|
1 |12-08-01 08:00 |12-08-01 09:00 |6001 |
5 |12-08-01 09:00 |12-08-01 10:00 |6001 |
7 |12-08-01 10:00 |12-08-01 11:00 |6002 |
9 |12-08-01 11:00 |12-08-01 12:00 |6002 |
15 |12-08-01 12:00 |12-08-01 13:00 |6003 |
27 |12-08-01 13:00 |12-08-01 14:00 |6001 |